# libgtest.so file not recognized , format not recognized

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, linker, googletest

I am trying to integrate googletest within my project.
I have build the googletest and generated gtest.so and gtest_main.so.
Moved these files to my lib folder and includes to my include folder.
The compilation works fine, but linking time it is unable to recognize the format of the gtest_main.so format.
Please let me know what could be the problem. Have I missed any option while doing google test build?

Steps I did to build googletest-:
1) clone code from https://github.com/google/googletest
2) cd googletest
3) cmake ..
4) make

CMakeLists.txt -> Enabled below flags
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) 
  set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

CMakeCache.txt 
  Made BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON

When the libgtest.so is generated copied *.so files to lib folder 
of my project.

Built my project which is a tizen project.
Received below error
libgtest.so : file not recognized, file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
clang++: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Missed an option, used the wrong option. Really who can say since you haven't given any detail on what you actually did.

Comment: Added some details. please let me know if more information is needed,

Comment: When you build gtest it is compiled for the OS and processor of your machine. Your Tizen project may be cross compiled for another OS or processor. Both projects need to be build for the same OS and processor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the fact that the test suite is built on the desktop and the target processor is the desktop one. Tizen projects, on the other hand, are cross-compiled for ARM processors. The Tizen SDK uses a separate stack to do build Tizen project and fails to use your library. Binaries built for non-ARM cannot be used with ARM binaries. Exactly like @rveerd wrote.

It's not necessary to compile googletest to be able to use it in Tizen projects.

Tizen SDK supports googletest and the simplest way to create test project that works on Tizen device is to use the template included in the SDK. The instruction at https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/native-tools/running-and-testing-your-app/unit-test says:

1. In the Tizen Studio menu, select `File` > `New` > `Other` > `Tizen` > `Tizen Native Unit Test Project`.
2. In the New Tizen Unit Test Project window:

   - In the Select the Tizen Project for test panel, select the project you want to test.
   - Specify a name for the test project.
   - Specify a destination folder where to save the project.
   - Click `Finish`

If you prefer to stay with the project you've created and copy the lib to the project, then you should use the .so file that matches the target architecture. To create one, you can build the googletest with Tizen SDK tools or try one that is build for Tizen already. There are Tizen RPMs containing the googletest libraries, e.g. http://download.tizen.org/releases/milestone/tizen/unified/tizen-unified_20200521.1/repos/standard/packages/armv7l/gstreamer-utils-1.16.2-24.1.armv7l.rpm .